# Why this error appears "GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!"?

Tags: python

I am performing a material removal from an object, via `bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()` into Blender 2.91
So far everything ok, so immediately after that script, I put a function that cleans the elements of the date, no longer in use.
It seemed to work fine, but in reality I get this error (Sometimes) and Blender crashes:
After various tests, I noticed that if I don't run the purge function, everything goes smoothly, no errors in any case.

[image]

So, the script looks something like this:

```
ob = context.object
mat = ob.active_material
if mat:
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()

def purge():
    orphan_ob = [o for o in bpy.data.objects if not o.users]
    while orphan_ob:
        bpy.data.objects.remove(orphan_ob.pop())
  
    orphan_mesh = [m for m in bpy.data.meshes if not m.users]
    while orphan_mesh:
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(orphan_mesh.pop())

    orphan_mat = [mat for mat in bpy.data.materials if not mat.users]
    while orphan_mat:
        bpy.data.materials.remove(orphan_mat.pop())

    def purge_node_groups():
        orphan_node_group = [g for g in bpy.data.node_groups if not g.users]

        while orphan_node_group:
            bpy.data.node_groups.remove(orphan_node_group.pop())
        if [g for g in bpy.data.node_groups if not g.users]: 
            purge_node_groups()

    purge_node_groups()
  
    orphan_texture = [t for t in bpy.data.textures if not t.users]
    while orphan_texture:
        bpy.data.textures.remove(orphan_texture.pop())
 
    orphan_images = [i for i in bpy.data.images if not i.users]
    while orphan_images:
        bpy.data.images.remove(orphan_images.pop())

    return 

purge()
```

Comment: Try removing the removing images line. If you look up the error message in the source code it occurs in `gpu_image.c` and `movieclip.c`  The error is thrown, and warning printed when the gpu texture has an invalid image or image buffer.